# VS Code is not sugging imports from inside the node_modules

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am experiencing issues when using **"V.S. Code"**. All of my settings were deleted (or that is the way it seems). I reinstalled V.S. Code, but now I cannot get auto imports to work.

##### For example:

When I write `useEffect`, I expect VS Code to suggest an import for it from the node modules, however, its not suggesting it.

[image]

###### *How can this issue be fixed?*

Comment: Have you reinstalled/synced your extensions aswell?

Comment: @Raqha yes, everything

Comment: First, make sure that you have the **["msjsdiag.vscode-react-native"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native-preview)**, and **"[`"VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode"`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)** installed. Then make sure that you have installed react using `$ npm i react-native`

Comment: Oh and make sure that the following settings are enabled by assigning the true boolean value to them both **`"javascript.suggest.autoImports": true`** & **`"javascript.suggest.includeCompletionsForImportStatements": true`**

Comment: Most likely you just didn't do one of those things that I mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer.
The problem was that by default the extension "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" was disabled. After enabling now everything work

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGp4H.png]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add this line to your VS Code "settings.json" file:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use language extension if vs code as Typescript React Js